# JavaScript Porto Type Not working

Tags: javascript, prototype

So im trying to get my prototype function to run but for some reason when i go to run the program its telling me that the prototype function is not a function. Could some one take a look and see what im doing incorrectly?

```js
function questions(questions){
  this.questions = questions;
}
questions.prototype.addquestion = function(){
  var questions = [];
  var ask = questions.push(this.questions);
  for(i=0; i<ask; i++){
    console.log(ask[0]); 
  }
}

questionone = new questions("question one");
questionone.addquestion();
```

Comment: Please elaborate, the issue [is not re-produceable](http://jsfiddle.net/t2LqpwLt/). Notice, that [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the length of an array, not another array.

Comment: Please show us the exact error message. As it is, your code doesn't trigger any errors.

Comment: I got it all to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are overriding the `questions` function to a variable:

```
questions.prototype.addquestion = function(){
   var aQuestions = [];
   var ask = aQuestions.push(this.questions);
   for(i=0; i<ask; i++){
       console.log(ask[0]); 
   }
 }
```

Change your array to another name and it must works.

Comment: @AlexGwartney Actually this doesn't change anything, you can use local `questions` variable name when it has been declared in `addquestion`, it's not overriding anything in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
function questions(questions){
  this.questions = questions;
}
questions.prototype.addquestion = function(){

  var questions = [];
  questions.push(this.questions); 
    for(i=0;i<questions.length; i++){
        console.log(questions[0]); 
    }
}

questionone = new questions("question one");
questionone.addquestion();
```

Working link can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/meghanagpal/pr4s6Lnk/